# CSS tricky hover effect

Tags: javascript, css

How can I display an image or text whenever I hover over an image? Can you guys help me?

An example:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to work on as a base? We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: You can use javascript to do that. If you could post an example on a site like JSFiddle we could give you more help.

Comment: I like the those diacritics in the word in the 3rd menu item. `Räätälöity` beautiful..

Comment: You can use divs for the popup text with absolute positioning within the buttons area and show/hide them on hover.

Answer (score 4):

This actually isn't complicated at all...  Use a similar HTML structure as below and just change the display property of the span on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/kkxfk/2/

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link Title<span>Link Desc.</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Use absolute positioning to position the span where you want it.
    ul li a span {
        display: none;
    }

```
ul li a:hover span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used it with my own idea and get fully satisfied ,you have to make 2 images, first non-texted and second with your text and hower on them..... try it.....

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .leftPan{width:200px; float:right;; margin-top:2px}

    #c1 {
     margin:6px;
     border: thin solid black;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     background: url(1.jpg) no-repeat;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    #c1:hover {
     background: url(2_photo.jpg) no-repeat;
    }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a background-image on the `a` element.

You can then control when it's visible with css

```
a:hover {
    background-image: url(url/to/img);
}
```

Like this

html

```
<nav>
    <a href="#Räätälöity-toimitus">Räätälöity-toimitus</a>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200&text=image" alt="Räätälöity toimitus" />
</nav>
```

css

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 7;
}
a:hover {
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/50x50/E8117F/E8117F/);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UpGKf/